# tor browser selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, tor

I'm using selenium with Tor but it's not working , i saw that there is a library for doing that but only with python . Can this be done with javascript ? I tried that but it doesn't work.

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('tor')
    .build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember, this can be done only from Java and Python.

Answer (score -1):

I had trouble getting the latest geckodriver (0.21.0) and Selenium (3.13.0) to fetch a web page after launching the Tor Browser Bundle.  I think it may be incompatibilities with the older Firefox version Tor uses and the geckodriver but am not sure.

If you're just trying to use selenium-webdriver to use the Tor network, try this:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

var options = new firefox.Options();

options.setPreference('network.proxy.type', 1) // manual proxy config
       .setPreference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
       .setPreference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
       .setPreference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', true) // resolve DNS over Tor
       .setPreference('network.proxy.socks_version', 5)


let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();

driver.get('https://example.com/')
```

You will need to run Tor using the expert bundle or install and run it natively.

Here's what I tried for actually getting Tor Browser to automate.  It launches everything correctly but never navigates to the page.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

var options = new firefox.Options();

options.setBinary('/home/me/Desktop/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser');
options.addArguments('--detach');

(async function run() {
    let driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .setFirefoxOptions(options)
        .build();

    await driver.get('https://example.com/')
})();
```

Just to re-iterate, this second example isn't working.  On Mint 18 and Tor Browser 7.5.6 (FF ESR 52.9.0) it launches Tor and the browser just fine, but will not navigate to a page.